# Get value from a multidimensional array based on a parameter

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to show a form based on a variable in the url. This is my array:

```
$blocks = array(
    'oc1' => array(
        'slugid' => 'oc1',
        'title' => 'One Column 1',
        'desc' => 'Block with text',
        'values' => array(
            'textarea',
            'title'
        )
    ),
    'oc2' => array(
        'slugid' => 'oc2',
        'title' => 'One Column 2',
        'desc' => 'Block with button',
        'values' => array(
            'title'
        )
    )

);
```

Now I want to show form fields based on the values array. So if my url is test.php?b=oc1 it should show the textarea field. If test.php?b=oc2 it should not because textarea is not added to the values array.

I've tried a lot of answers I found on StackOverflow but I can't get it to work. 
So if anyone knows how to do this I would be very very grateful.

Comment: If `textarea` is `in_array` `'values'` - show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if is defined the `$_GET` variable (if you have not done it before) and using the [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function check if `textarea` value exist in your two-dimensional array.

```
if (isset($_GET['b']) && in_array('textarea', $blocks[$_GET['b']]['values']))
{
    echo 'textarea';
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Didn't know it was so simple, thank you! :)

I now would like to turn this into a function, in order to use this for every field. But that doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

<?php
function allowfield($content,$actualfield) {
 if (isset($content) && in_array($actualfield, $blocks[$content]['values'])) 
  return true;
}

$blockcode = $_GET[ "b" ];

if (allowfield($blockcode,'textarea')){ ?> Yes show the textarea HTML <?php } ?>

Comment: Try to pass also the `$blocks` variable as parameter of the function since it's not a global variable.